# Finding Particular Intergrals for ODE's, Is it okay if particular integral varies?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

### The equation to solve :  $y''-6y'+9y=e^{3x}$

This is the general solution from wolframalpha :

> $y(x) = c_2 e^{3 x} x + c_1 e^{3 x} + 1/2 e^{3x} x^{2}$

This is the solution I calculated from the method of undetermined coefficients :

> $y(x) = c_2 e^{3 x} x + c_1 e^{3 x} + Ax^2 e^{3x}$

This is the solution I calculated using the 'D' operator and shortcut method :

> $y(x) = c_2 e^{3 x} x + c_1 e^{3 x} + e^{3x}/18$

I think I'm getting different particular integrals while using different methods because this differential equation has a family of solutions ?

But the fact that the last solution's P.I doesn't even have an 'x' term concerns me.

All of them are correct, am I right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing the solution $y(x) = b e^{3 x} x + a e^{3 x} + c x^2 e^{3x}$, we get

$$2c e^{3 x} \ne e^{3x}$$

This is not a solution.

---

Testing the solution $y(x) = b e^{3 x} x + a e^{3 x} + e^{3x}/18$, we get

$$0 \ne e^{3x}$$

This is not a solution.

---

Testing the solution, $y(x) = c_2 e^{3 x} x + c_1 e^{3 x} + 1/2 e^{3x} x^{2}$, we get

$$e^{3x} = e^{3x}$$

This is a solution.

---

Now, lets use [*Undetermined Coefficients*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx) to solve $y''-6y'+9y=e^{3x}$.

For the homogeneous solution, we have $ m^2 - 6 m + 9 = 0 \implies m_{1,2} = 3$, hence

$$y_h(x) = e^{3x}( c_1 + c_2 x)$$

Because our homogeneous solution, $e^{3x}(c_1 + c_2 x)$ shares the RHS $e^{3x}$, we choose $$y_p(x) = a x^2 e^{3x}$$

Substituting, we have

$$y_p(x)''-6y_p(x)'+9y_p(x) = 2 a e^{3x} =e^{3x} \implies a = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

We can now write

$$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x) = e^{3x}( c_1 + c_2 x + \dfrac{1}{2} x^2)$$

Comment: But yp = $e^{3x}/18$ solves the ODE for that particular value, so is that not a particular integral ?

Comment: Yes, but you would absorb that into the homogeneous result as we would have $$a e^{3 x} + e^{3x}/18 = d e^{3 x} $$ Clear? It is just splitting the general constant.

Comment: You mean the 'a' in yp accounts for all the different constants ?

But then, $e^{3x}/18$ doesnt even have an $x^2$ term ?

I'm confused, I'm sorry I can't help it, I'm dumb ... :/

Comment: The homogeneous solution is  $y_h(x) = e^{3x}( c_1 + c_2 x)$. The claimed particular solution is $e^{3x}/18$. You can just combine the $c_1 e^{3x}$ term with the $e^{3x}/18$ term as a single term. In other words, there is no particular solution to talk about.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm so sorry, I made a mistake, 

( I thought $e^{3x}/18$ solved the non-homogeneous equation.)

Now I got it !

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Make the Ansatz $$y_P=Ax^2e^{3x}$$ where $A$ is a real number.

Comment: Yes, from the method of undetermined coefficients, I got  yp as $ Ax^2 e^{3x}$ 

But, are the other solutions mentioned in the question correct ?